# jquery ajax call in confirm button

Tags: jquery

Hi I written the ajax call inside if(confirm.... condition but it is not going to my ajax page. If i write  $.get outside of if(confirm(.... then it is working fine.

What is the problem. please tell me some one.

```
function ConfirmSave() {    
    if (confirm("Do You Want to Save the test?")) 
    {          
        $.get('../Common/Ajax.aspx',{action:"UpdateExamDuration",UserExamMapID:UserExamMap});        
    }                
    document.location.href = "../Reports/Report-Card.aspx";       
}
```

Comment: Did you check what "confirm('Do you...')" is returning ?

Comment: Maybe your `document.location.href = ` is triggering before the ajax call can happen?

Comment: I think NADH is right, try setting `document.location.href` in the success handler of your `get` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the trailing brace `}` (probably just left that in there, right?) it worked for me, in that the ajax request was fired. I saw this because I had persist mode on in FireBug (meaning that request was still visible after I was redirected with the last line). What you want to do is put the `document.location.href` inside the `$.get` callback, meaning it will only run once it has completed:

```
if (confirm("Do You Want to Save the test?")) 
    {          
        $.get('../Common/Ajax.aspx', {action:"UpdateExamDuration",UserExamMapID:UserExamMap}, function(data){document.location.href = "../Reports/Report-Card.aspx";});        
    }                
}
```

Comment: thank you leonard challis, it is working fine now if i write as you said

Comment: Ah good :) Feel free to set this as the accepted answer so others know too ;)